# Jquery callback/closure problem

Tags: jquery, callback, closures

I've written a jquery plugin like this

```
(function($){

$.inspect = function(prodid, flag, callback){
    //global plugin vars
    var inspect, info, tabs, generalInfo;

    var init = function(){
        //build basic layout
        //use of prodid and flag is ok
    }

    var fetch = function(){
        //fetch data
        //use of prodid and flag is ok
    }

    var render = function(){
        //render data
        //use of prodid and flag is ok
    }

    var empty = function(){
        //reset to basic layout
        //use of prodid and flag is ok
    }

    var listeners = function(){
        //bind eventhandlers
        //use of prodid or flag FAILS here
        inspect.dialog('option','close', /* how to put callback here? */ callback );


    }

    //existing instance?
    inspect = $(".inspectHolder");
    if(inspect.length>0){//existing instance
        inspect = $(".inspectHolder");
        info = $(".inspectInfo", inspect);
        tabs = $(".inspectTabs", inspect);
        empty();
    }
    else{//new instance
        init();
    }

}
```

})

first plugin call

```
prodid = 100
$.inspect( prodid, 0, function(){
    console.log(prodid);
});
```

second plugin call

```
prodid = 200
$.inspect( prodid, 0 , function(){
    console.log(prodid)
});
```

Now my problem is the following:

binding my event handlers makes every event use the first prodid (=100) and not the one I pass as a parameter to the $.inspect() call...
Everything else works just fine

i know i could just make a new instance for every $.inspect() call but that would be unclean or wise (memorymanagement?) ( as far as i know, still pretty new to programming)

I tried using callback.call(this, prodid) or some things similar, but its more like just try and see what happens then really understanding what it's for...some decent docs on this would be very welcome, as i find the jquery docs on this insufficient (or i'm just looking over something)

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thx body

Comment: Attached code is shattered a bit... Where's definition of inspect.dialog('option','close' ? As for using call on functions in javascript. The first element you pass is a context, an object that will be available in given function using *this* keyword. The rest of the parameters passed to *call* are the same attributes that will be passed to the function we're calling. Your question covers a lot of different topics (how to use callback, how to pass callbacks, how to structure a plugin etc) so it's hard to provide usable answer. Docs for call function: http://goo.gl/pC27s

Comment: I'm well aware my question covers more topics then those mentioned in the title, nevertheless i feel structure is quite an important aspect (if not the most important). There is alot of snippets out there with some info on a specific topic, but i havent found a site/manual/book which covers structuring  all these topics into one well-organized project. Or maybe i'm not that good in googling as i thought i was. Anyhow, the dialog('option','close',callback) comes from the jquery ui. as for my code being shattered:i know i need to improve, but for now i only need a solution to the problem at hand